# Why is XmlParser converting my character hex code string to unicode?

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, xml-parsing, xml-entities

In my Grails application I use Groovy's [XmlParser](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html) to parse an XML file.  The value of one of the attributes in my XML file is a string that equals a character hex code.  I want to save that string in my database:

`&#xD1;`

Unfortunately the [attribute](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Node.html#attribute%28java.lang.Object%29) method returns the **Ñ** character and what actually gets stored in the database is `c391`.  When the field is read back out I also get the **Ñ** character  which is undesired.

How can I store the hex code as a string in my database and make sure it gets read back out as a hex code as well?

**Update #1:**

The reason this is a problem for me is that once I read the XML file into my database I must be able to reconstruct it exactly as it was.  An additional problem is that the field in question isn't always a character hex code. It could just be some arbitrary string.

**Update #2:**

I guess it doesn't matter how the character is stored in the database, so long as I can write it back out in its expanded hex code format.  I am using Groovy [MarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html) to reconstruct my XML file from the database and I am unclear why this isn't happening by default.

**Update #3:**

I overrode `getTableTypeString` in my custom MySQL dialect and that seems to have helped things some what.  At least now the value I pass to MySQL is the value that gets stored in the database.

```
class CustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {   
    @Override
    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
    }
}
```

I also created my own version of [groovy.util.XmlParser](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/util/XmlParser.java).  My version is pretty much an exact duplicate of `groovy.util.XmlParser` except that in the `startElement` method I changed:

```
String value = list.getValue(i)
```

to this:

```
def value = list.fAttributes.fAttributes[i].nonNormalizedValue
if(value ==~ /&#x([0-9A-F]+?);/) {
    value = list.fAttributes.fAttributes[i].nonNormalizedValue
}
```

This allows the exact text of hex code elements to be stored in the database.

Now there are two new problems, possibly three.

1. Recreating a file with the exact values stored in the database.  Up till now I had been using `MarkupBuilder`, but that is doing extra encoding on ampersands, causing the value `&#xD1;` to be written out as `&amp;#xD1;`  I can probably get around this by abandoning `MarkupBuilder` and building my XML strings manually, but I would rather not.
2. Running an XSLT transform on an XML file using the Saxon-HE 9.4 processor causes some hex code values such as `&#xFF;` to be changed to something like **ÿ**, yet others like `&#x99;` are left unchanged.
3. I'm not sure if this is going to be a problem yet or not, but when I recreate the file I would like it to be in `ANSI` encoding since that is the encoding used for the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so given the xml:

```
def xml = '''<root>
    <node woo="&#xD1;"/>
    <another attr="This is an N-Tilde - &#xD1;"/>
</root>'''
```

We can read that attribute into a variable:

```
def woo = new XmlParser().parseText( xml ).node[0].@woo
```

And printing it out give us `'Ñ'` (with a character value of `209`)

But that's what I'd expect...  as `&#xD1;` is the same as `&#209;` which is the [correct encoding for N-tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%91#Computer_usage)

Ahhh, so is the question *"How can I read attributes, and keep them as-is without any entity resolving"*?

I don't believe you can (all I've seen is negative answers from a search of the web)...  What you could do is something like:

```
// Mask entities

xml = xml.replaceAll( /&#x([0-9A-F]+?);/, '!!#x$1;' )

def parser = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

println parser.node[0].@attr.replaceAll( /!!#x([0-9A-F]+?);/, '&#x$1;' )
println parser.another[0].@attr.replaceAll( /!!#x([0-9A-F]+?);/, '&#x$1;' )
```

But as far as I know, there's not a method for tuning off entity resolution :-(  (fingers crossed I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0):

> The value of one of the attributes in my XML file is a string that equals a character hex code

No it isn't.  The *representation* of the attribute value in the original XML is a hexadecimal character reference, but the *value* of the attribute is the character Ñ.  There are ways to configure some XML parsers to avoid expanding named *entity* references during parsing, but they *must* expand numeric character references as per the XML spec.

You haven't said why storing the real character value is a problem.  If it's to do with rendering the value to a browser then that can be handled by using `.encodeAsHTML()` at output time.  If you need to save the value to another XML file then use an XML API to do so and it will handle the encoding issues for you, replacing characters with entities or character references where this is required to keep the result well-formed (in the case of Ñ it doesn't need to be escaped anyway unless you're writing XML in an unusual character set).

In the specific case of Groovy's MarkupBuilder you can temporarily escape from XML mode and write hand-constructed markup directly to the output stream using [`mkp.yieldUnescaped`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilderHelper.html#yieldUnescaped%28java.lang.String%29), which would let you output a character reference somewhere the builder wouldn't normally bother.

Comment: I updated my question to indicate why this is a problem for me.

Comment: @ubiquibacon if your code cares about the difference between Ñ, `&#xD1;`, `&#xd1;`, etc. then you can't use an XML tool to parse the data. An XML parser simply will not tell you which lexical representation was used in the original source.

Comment: I have added some new information to my question.  It doesn't look like I can use any SAX based parser to read the character hex code as a string, but maybe you know a way I can make Groovy [MarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html) (or equivalent) write out offending characters in their expanded hex code format.

Comment: @ubiquibacon an XML API will escape anything that needs to be escaped and not anything that doesn't. If you're writing XML in UTF-8 then `Ñ` can be written without escaping. If you write it as US-ASCII then it would get escaped as `&#xD1;` or `&#209;` or some other equivalent character reference. I'll say it again - if you care about this level of detail then you're not dealing with XML and you can't use an XML tool, instead you'll have to construct the markup yourself as strings.

Comment: I am writing the XML in UTF-8 and Ñ gets written to the file. Besides my requirement to be able to generate XML identical to what I had as an input the Saxon-HE parser chokes on that character. That is how I discovered this issue.

Comment: @ubiquibacon the encoding you're telling Saxon to use when reading the file must be something other than UTF-8. Are you maybe using a FileReader rather than giving Saxon access to the raw byte stream so it can detect the encoding itself? You should probably ask this as a separate question with the relevant code snippet and example XML.

Comment: Yeah, there are obviously several factors playing into all of this. I'll try to figure out a bit more about what is going on so I can ask the appropriate question(s). Thanks for your help.