# Insert ampersand into MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is an extension of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039948/why-is-xmlparser-converting-my-character-hex-code-string-to-unicode).

In a simple test to gather more information for the question I linked to I tried to insert an ampersand character into my database through the phpMyAdmin interface...

```
INSERT INTO `my_db`.`some_table` (`id`, `version`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '0', '&');
```

... but what gets inserted is the HTML equivalent `&amp;`.

My database collation is `utf8_bin`, the table I'm inserting into is `utf8_general_ci`, and the field I'm attempting to insert the ampersand into is of type `varchar`.

What must I do to insert the raw ampersand character `&` into my MySQL database?

**Update:**

I don't know what the problem with phpMyAdmin is, but I think I found the problem with my application.  It seems that Hibernate just wasn't using the correct character set for the connection.  I already had a custom MySQL dialect specified so I just overrode the `getTableTypeString` method as seen below and my application now inserts values into MySQL properly:

```
class CustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {   
    @Override
    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The best way to store &(Ampersand) in MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704233/the-best-way-to-store-ampersand-in-mysql-database)

Comment: This might be a case of the web interface of phpMyAdmin messing this up for you. Have you tried running this query directly inside MySQL or via some program language?

Comment: I have only tried running the query through phpMyAdmin and through the connection created by my Grails application. Both yield the same result. I'll try using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO The question you linked to is asking what is the best way to store an ampersand. Apparently the OP of that question knows how to store an ampersand in either format `&` or `&amp;`.  My question is asking why is the HTML format being stored when I am attempting to store a raw ampersand character `&`.

Comment: I just tried this, I'm running phpMyAdmin 4.0.1-rc1.  It works fine, it does not convert & to &amp;  I also tested in the MySQL command-line client, and it works the same.

Comment: I think the issue is not with storing the `&` value in mysql. The issue seems to be with the retrieval.

Comment: @MikeBrant I just wiped all data from the database then inserted an `&` using MySQL Workbench and the query in my question. The `&` character was stored, not the HTML equivalent. I then ran the same query again using phpMyAdmin and the `&` character was stored, not the HTML equivalent. Something weird is going on here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem either, with phpMyAdmin 4.0.7.

Comment: @ubiquibacon: which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: @MarcDelisle I'm using an older version, 3.4.5  Guess it is time to upgrade.

Comment: @ubiquibacon: I cannot reproduce with 3.4.5 either.

Comment: @MarcDelisle I don't know what the deal is with phpMyAdmin, but I think the character set my application was using to connect to MySQL was causing my problems.  See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
INSERT INTO `my_db`.`some_table` (`id`, `version`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '0', _utf8'&');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem with phpMyAdmin is, but I think I found the problem with my application. It seems that Hibernate just wasn't using the correct character set for the connection. I already had a custom MySQL dialect specified so I just overrode the getTableTypeString method as seen below and my application now inserts values into MySQL properly:

class CustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
    @Override
    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
    }
}